# HTML5 : Input field with the type of 'number' will still accept higher value than its 'max' using keyboard inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello guys need some help here. i want to have limit the numbers inputted in my input field by putting max attribute to it. i have no problem with that until i use my keyboard to input data on it. seems like the max attribute is not filtering the input coming from the keyboard.

e.g

```
<input type="number" max="5" />
```

i can't go until `6` using the up and down arrow but when i manually put `6` using keyboard it's accepts it. how can i prevent? thank you

Comment: Does it not give an error when you try to submit the form? (Or is there no form?)

Comment: Yes. That is the way it works. It will invalidate however, when the form submits or you validate it yourself.

Comment: You can add a JavaScript that oninput alerts when the number is not in range.

Comment: yes @AlivetoDie i upvoted rostovtsev answer since its very specific not allowing user to input value greater that the max. thanks guys

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would need to use *JavaScript* to do it. This will not let the *user* enter a number higher than **5**:

```html
 <input type="number" max="5" onkeyup="if(this.value > 5) this.value = null;">
```

Another possible solution is to completely block the keyboard input by replacing `onkeyup=".."` event in the code above with `onkeydown="return false"`.

Comment: Seems like you could still paste a value higher than 5 in it.

Comment: @Somethingwhatever You could use the other event, like `onblur` or properly handle multiple events in a dedicated handler.

Answer (score 2):

> have no problem with that until i use my keyboard to input data on it.
>   seems like the max attribute is not filtering the input coming from
>   the keyboard

This is how HTML5 validation/constraint work. However, it will invalidate when the form submits. Alternatively, you can validate it yourself. To validate yourself, you need to wire up Javascript and call the `checkValidity()` on the input element.

`checkValidity()` of the constraints API will check the validity state of the element and will return the state of whether the input element validate or not. This will also set the `validity` object on the input so that you can query more details.

Ref: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#constraints and https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#form-submission-algorithm

You can also use the `:invalid` selector in CSS to highlight invalid inputs.

**Example Snippet:**

```js
var input = document.getElementById('test'), 
    result = document.getElementById('result');
  
input.addEventListener('blur', validate);

function validate(e) {
  var isValid = e.target.checkValidity();
  result.textContent = 'isValid = ' + isValid;
  if (! isValid) {
    console.log(e.target.validity);
  }
}
```

```css
input[type=number]:invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<label>Enter value and press tab: </label><br/>
<input id="test" type="number" min="1" max="10" />
<hr/>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: "However, it will invalidate when the form submits." If this doesn't happen, your form probably has `novalidate="novalidate"`, like mine did…

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript` to restrict the maximum input value to 5.

**HTML**

using `oninput` as a event handler

```
<input type="number" max="5" oninput="checkLength(this)" />
```

**JS**

```
function checkLength(elem) {
  // checking if iput value is more than 5
  if (elem.value > 5) {
    alert('Max value is 5')
    elem.value = ''; // emptying the input box
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/dsz627ch/)

Answer (score 0):

## An Utility Function to Solve Two Problem

### Problem 1: Limit user input to maximum n digit

*For this use n number of 9 as max parameter. As an example if you want to limit user input in 4 digit then max param value will be 9999.*

### Problem 2: Limit user input at a maximum value

*This is intuitive. As an example If you want restrict the user input to maximum 100 then max param value will be 100.*

```
function getMaxInteger(value, max) {
    if(!value) return;
    if( parseInt(value) <= max ) {
        return value;
    }
    return getMaxInteger(value?.substr(0, value?.length-1), max);
}

function maxInt(value, max) {
    return getMaxInteger(value?.replace(/\D/,''), max);
}
```

#### Use this maxInt method on input change handler

ngModelChange for **Angular**

onChange for **React**

v-on:change or watch for **Vue**

Answer (score -1):

```
onkeyup="if(this.value > <?=$remaining?>) this.value = null; else if(this.value < 1) this.value = null;"
```

Comment: Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.